# can't build project after installing react native contacts

Tags: react-native, react-native-contacts

after installing the "react-native contacts" i get error in run time and it cant download gardle 4.1.0, so what i did just running command "npm i react-native-contacts" and my project config is like below:

pachage.json

```
"react-native": "0.68.1",
"react-native-contacts": "^7.0.5",
```

gardel.build:

```
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

and the error is this:

```
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-contacts:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.jar
```

i tried proxy to download it but it not works, i event could download it by browser(by the way im in iran, don't know if it related)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Portugal and the link to the .jar works in my browser.

Comment: the point is it's work in my browser to, but after run for android it gives the error